# CodeIgniter Site is not working after changing domain and move on another hosting

Tags: codeigniter, hosting

I have a CodeIgniter site on production and the URL is http://example.com/ear, it means site is running as folder structure.

Now I am moving the site from production to another staging environment and also changing the domain to http://ear.example.com. I have change the base URL in config file and also the database details under database.php but the site is showing 500 error. The error is "ear.abc.com is currently unable to handle this request."

Can someone help me? I am copying my `.htaccess` file here. Please feel free to write me for any query.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

**NOTE:** I can't share the exact domain name due to client policy so I am taking "example" in place of actual domain name.

Comment: have you did some basic checks ?  put sample `index.html` in that subdomain and check weather its working or not.. if it works than just put `die("Hello");` on first line of `index.php` and investigate further.

Comment: Thanks for give me a path. I checked by printing hello and it reached there.

Comment: Now try to put multiple echo on file and try to locate the line at which it stop. Mostly it should be at required step. Thai jase.. chinta na karo. ;)

Comment: I dig the code and it seems that error is coming after the link require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help! It was an issue with one of used ldpa_connect class. The extension was missing from my hosting.

Comment: Good job vipul    :)